# How to write the condition in SSRS for dynamically changing color of the cell based on value

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2014, msbi

How to write the condition in SSRS for dynamically changing color of the cell based on value

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XHL4.png

Comment: This existing answer might help you: [change color depending on value SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724228/change-color-depending-on-value-ssrs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this:

```
=IIf((Fields!nbday.Value >= 0 and Fields!nbday.Value < 90) ,"#3174c3",IIf((Fields!nbday.Value >= 90 and Fields!nbday.Value < 120),"#02C1D3","No Color"))
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Choose the Cell / Row / Column that you want to Change the color dynamically
2. Go to Properties (Hit F4)
3. Select Back Ground Color and Choose Expression
4. In the provided window, Give your Expression based on which the color will change.

Refer [This Link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3490/alternate-row-background-color-in-sql-server-reporting-services-tablix-and-matrix/) for more details